# Heroku: Problem with deploying cherrypy app

Tags: heroku, deployment, cherrypy

I'm basically trying to deploy the example in the CherryPy tutorial to Heroku (https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-8-make-it-smoother-with-ajax). When I run the code locally, everything works fine. After deployment to Heroku, I get several error messages:

```
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422074+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422076+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422076+00:00 app[web.1]: response.body = self.handler()
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422076+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 217, in __call__
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422077+00:00 app[web.1]: self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422077+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 61, in __call__
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422078+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422078+00:00 app[web.1]: File "app.py", line 19, in GET
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422078+00:00 app[web.1]: return cherrypy.session['mystring']
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422079+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/__init__.py", line 246, in __getitem__
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422079+00:00 app[web.1]: return child[key]
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422079+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py", line 309, in __getitem__
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422080+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._data[key]
2020-04-16T17:42:19.422080+00:00 app[web.1]: KeyError: 'mystring'
```

```
2020-04-17T09:24:31.597650+00:00 app[web.1]: File "app.py", line 45, in <module>
2020-04-17T09:24:31.597765+00:00 app[web.1]: webapp.generator = StringGeneratorWebService()
2020-04-17T09:24:31.597768+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: expose_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
2020-04-17T09:24:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

My Procfile simply contains

```
web: python app.py
```

My guess is that the problem has something to do with the little css-trick that avoids refreshing the page in order display the result of a request. But, as you can see, I'm totally new to deployment and this is also my first question on stackoverflow--so my apologies in advance in case I'm missing something obvious here. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `KeyError: 'mystring'` happens because you're trying to get a value from the session that doesn't yet exist. It'll appear once you do the first `POST`. You could alternatively use `.get()` syntax instead of `[]` if you want a fallback (b/c it's a dict-like object).

Comment: Also, I suppose you redeployed the app once or twice. Heroku recreates containers each time and the default session storage is based on files on disk which are not transferred to each new clean container. With things like heroku, you should resort to configuring an external persistent storage as a backend for keeping sessions there. One way to do this is to configure CherryPy to use memcached.

Comment: The second error seems less obvious. I'd need to see the exact code you're running + versions of all the software.

Comment: Also, drop by https://gitter.im/cherrypy/cherrypy to get more interactive help (log in via GitHub).